# MS SQL Server Agent Jobs sometimes stands

Tags: sql-server, jobs, sql-server-agent

Although the SQL Server Agent service jobs have started then cut and run, sometimes does not work until you restart the jobs related ever again. Why might that be?

[image]

Comment: Having a job that needs to run every 20 seconds of every day is indicative of a design flaw. Sadly I have to support a few systems that do this.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a request queue. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Eser, please explain your requirements further. Perhaps as an edit to your question? What exactly does the job do? Perhaps even include your code.

Comment: A windows service, listening to the queue in a continuous loop. system makes the process look to those requests. This queue data is made according to certain information in the database and this is happening every 20 seconds. Windows service is not dependent on for 20 seconds. Windows service while doing transactions take all of the data queue. Meanwhile, the queue builds up .... each cycle takes longer than 20 seconds. Meanwhile not have the same data in the queue.

Comment: I fear that this is going to take a lot more discussion than comments allow. But I would look in to changing whatever the windows process does... it seems strange to me to have two separate loops for a single purpose. A single, self-serving loop would be more efficient/robust in almost all cases. If you want to discuss further tag me in another comment and we can try open up a chat session.

Comment: I'm understand. thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you answered the question yourself: "sometimes does not work until you restart the jobs related ever again"

so this job although it is recurring, wont continue because its dependant on other jobs? Best answer I can give with what you provided. What other jobs is this depending on? Are they recurring as well? See where this can get complicated real quick when you dont give enough info in your question?

i.e. this job(although recurring) wont continue if it needs another job to kick start it into action

Hope this helps you out.